# Secret Santa Sorting Hat

Tags: python, arrays, function, loops, random

I'm working on a program that will simulate a sorting hat for Secret Santa. I'm trying to get the program to have an error trap to prevent people from getting their own names, however I'm not able to get the program to choose a new name in the event someone gets their own name. Another problem I'm encountering is that the program keeps exiting prematurely.

Here's my code:

```
import random
print "Testing Arrays"
Names=[0,1,2,3,4]
#0 - Travis 
#1 - Eric 
#2 - Bob 
#3 - Tim 
#4 - Dhyan
x = 1
z = True
def pick(x):
    while (z == True):
        #test=input("Is your Name Travis?")
        choice = random.choice(Names) #Picks a random choice from Names Array
        if (choice == 0): #If it's Travis
            test=input("Is your Name Travis?") #Asking user if they're Rabbit
            if(test == "Yes"):
                return "Pick Again"
            elif(test== "No"):
                return "You got Travis"
                Names.remove(1)
                break
        elif (choice == 1):
            test=input("Is your Name Eric?")
            if(test=="Yes"):
                return "Pick Again"
            elif(test=="No"):
                Names.remove(2)
                return "You got Eric"
                break

print pick(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

While this may not be exactly how you want to organize your program, the example provides an example of one way to prevent individuals from giving gifts to themselves. It uses something similar to a do/while loop available in some other languages to make sure `targets` pass the requirements.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import random


def main():
    names = 'Travis', 'Eric', 'Bob', 'Rose', 'Jessica', 'Anabel'
    while True:
        targets = random.sample(names, len(names))
        if not any(a == b for a, b in zip(targets, names)):
            break
    # If Python supported do/while loops, you might have written this:
    # do:
    #     targets = random.sample(names, len(names)
    # while any(a == b for a, b in zip(targets, names))
    for source, target in zip(names, targets):
        print('{} will give to {}.'.format(source, target))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Ask for the users name first, then use a while loop to keep fetching random names while random name equals input name.